# Change bufferedImage pixels in java

Tags: java, image, java-8, bufferedimage, bitwise-operators

I have a small problem.
I have a BufferedImage which has pixels that have an RGB value.
This code is used to create an RGB value from de R, G, B, A values.

```
private int getRGB(int r, int g, int b, int a){
    return (a << 24) | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
}
```

The first question is, how can i get the R, G, B, A values from a Pixel, because the pixel RGB will return the number that is generated by the code above.

And if I have those values, can I put 2 pixels on top of each other so it calculates the new values or do I have to do that by manual?
With automatic calculation you can think of Java 2D  when you put 2 transport things on top it will merge the colors.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For second part of the question, see [Alpha compositing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing). However, if you can just use Java 2D, that would make life easier, as it already has Porter/Duff alpha compositing implemented (see `Graphics2D` and `AlphaComposite` classes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The first question is, how can i get the R, G, B, A values from a Pixel, because the pixel RGB will return the number that is generated by the code above.

You can reverse the process as follows:

```
int a = (argb >> 24) & 0xFF;
int r = (argb >> 16) & 0xFF;
int g = (argb >>  8) & 0xFF;
int b = (argb >>  0) & 0xFF;
```

> And if I have those values, can I put 2 pixels on top of each other so it calculates the new values or do I have to do that by manual? With automatic calculation you can think of Java 2D when you put 2 transport things on top it will merge the colors.

You will need to do this manually (or invoking a utility method per-pixel), since you need to decide how to composite the colors, e.g. you could use the maximum, sum, mean etc pixel value.

Comment: Of course, the programmer has to decide how the composition should be done, but once the decision has been made, there’s a rich API called AWT/Java2D that can be [utilized for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html)   [the task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite(java.awt.Composite)); [`BufferedImage.createGraphics()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#createGraphics()) makes it possible. Unless we learn why the OP said “you can think of Java 2D” instead of just using Java 2D…